# How to update one value in mysql table without updating the entire column

Tags: java, mysql, database, combobox

I'm trying to update one value in a MySql table using Java but my code updates the entire column in which the specified value is included.

I've tried using the LIMIT feature like

```
String sql = "UPDATE Task SET Status=? WHERE deadline = ? and name = ? order by deadline LIMIT 1";
```

but the program still updates the entire 'status' column not just one value. I've also tried adding 2 specifications using `WHERE` but it still doesn't work.

There's no error message.

Help? Thanks!!

Comment: There is no place for a limit or order by in this query. You just have to make sure the correct row or rows are selected by your where clause. If you want a single row, specify something that selects that row. Perhaps a primary key value if you have one?

Comment: Why you need an order by in update query ?

Comment: @kiranMohan `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is meaningless.  But, I'm not sure the OP's current syntax can be made to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try phrasing your update using a subquery to identify the earliest deadline:

```
UPDATE Task
SET Status = ?
WHERE deadline = (SELECT min_deadline FROM
                     (SELECT MIN(deadline) AS min_deadline FROM Task) x) AND
      name = ?;
```